# C# Web Service - Deploy on my website

Tags: service

I have a website and also connected in SQL Server.

How do I deploy my Web Service in my Web Site? Do I have to create a Virtual Directory?

am using HELM

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I have done it.

I just added this nodes in my Web.Config

```
<webServices><protocols><add name="HttpGet"/><add name="HttpPost"/></protocols></webServices>
```

and it worked.

Now I can make a Windows Forms and add Web Reference pointing on .asmx file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you developed the web service or going to develop one?

Generally, you do not need the web service files to be in a dedicated virtual directory, it's an `asmx` file just like an `aspx` file with code behind.

Comment: thanks.

I tried uploading it on my web server and it returned
"The test form is only available for requests from the local machine."

what should I change?

Comment: Are you using framework 1.1? You might want to check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267

Comment: no. actually, the Web Service I was going to create is for BlogEngine.NET | Am starting to make some test to return the categories through Web Service. | and how do I insert new line in this comment box??